# The current build parameters/ENV Variables in different build steps

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to define a new build parameter/ENV variable in a build step so it was available in the next one?

Let's say I have 2 different "Execute shell" steps and want in the second step access the variable defined in the first one.

**PS**: the value for the variable is set in runtime - read from 3rd party resource, so I cannot harcode it, thus need to set it from the shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) will do that for you.
It can be configured as `pre-SCM` step or as `build` steps. Put it in between your two existing build steps.

**Update**

In your case, it may be easier to just read the value of the "3rd party" file as part of your *second* build step:

```
var=$(<3rdpartyfile.txt)
```

After the above line, the contents of your `3rdpartyfile.txt` will be available in environment variable `var`. You can now use `$var` as you would any other variable

Comment: How could I set the value of the env variable from the 3rd party resource? Or, for sake of simplicity, local file? So, there is a file - I need to set its value as a ENV variable. How to do that with EnvInject?

Comment: If the file is in format `key=value`, you just supply this filename to the EnvInject plugin and the `value` will be available under environment variable called `key` that is global for this job run. You can then reference this env variable in your second build-step as you would any other environment variable. Come to think of it... you may simple write a script as part of your second build step that will read a value from that file... no need for any plugins. Are you using Linux of Windows? And what's the format of this 3rd party file?

Comment: it's linux. The file is a one line string. So I need to have it as a ENV variable value.

Comment: It's called "subshell" really, and above is just a shorthand way of reading a file. You can read about it here http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities and here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: Well, this didn't work: I've used `ID=$(< ip)` in a "predefined parameters" of a "trigger other build" plugin and the `$(< ip)` thing isn't resolved into the file contents, but passed as-is, as a `ID=$(< ip)` string :-(

Comment: No, no. The subshell syntax cannot be used in "predefined parameters". This was an *alternative* to using EnvInject plugin: **instead** of using EnvInject, simply have the second build step (which is a shell script) read that value from 3rd party file using the subshell syntax.

Comment: but from what I remember - environment variables set by shell script doesn't propagate to next build steps

Comment: That is correct. I am also going by what you stated in your requirements (in OP + in comments). So, lets clarify the requirements first: 1) You have one job 2) Job has 2 'execute shell' build steps 3) 1st build step results in a file 'ip' 4) You need the value from file 'ip' in an env variable available in 2nd build step. Answer) In the beginning of the 2nd build step, put `ID=$( < ip )` and now you can use `$ID` as a variable in second build step. --- However I am thinking that you are not telling all your requirements, as later you mention "trigger other build". Please update OP with all req

Comment: actually I figured it out. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like

```
stage('stage-1') {
    steps {
        script{
        env.variable = ${value};
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the variable env.variable throughout the pipeline